# Ошибка с strcpy

Tags: c, алгоритм, файлы, строки

В данном коде в функции findNearEquals вылетает ошибка доступа к памяти, помогите найти её

Вот код:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale>
#include <string.h>


int findMin(FILE *fileInput, FILE *fileOutput) {
    int min = INT32_MAX;
    int m[20];
    char buffer[100], element[5];

    fseek(fileInput, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fgets(buffer, 100, fileInput);
    strcpy(element,strtok(buffer, " "));

    for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
        m[i] = atoi(element);
        strcpy(element, strtok(NULL, " "));
        if (m[i] < min && m[i] % 2 == 0) min = m[i];
    }
    fprintf(fileOutput, "min = %d", min);

    return ftell(fileOutput);
}
int generateM(int m[], FILE *fileInput) {
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        m[i] = rand() % 32;
        fprintf(fileInput, "%d ", m[i]);
    }
    return ftell(fileInput);
}
void findNearEquals(FILE *fileInput, FILE *fileOutput,
    int posInInput, int posInOutput) {

    char buffer[100], element[100];
    int count = 0;

    int** mm;
    mm = new int*[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        mm[i] = new int[10];

    fseek(fileInput, posInInput+2, SEEK_SET);
    fseek(fileOutput, posInOutput, SEEK_SET);

    fgets(buffer, 100, fileInput);
    strcpy(element, strtok(buffer, " "));

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            mm[i][j] = atoi(element);
            strcpy(element, strtok(NULL, " "));
        }
        fgets(buffer, 100, fileInput);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            if (mm[i][j] == mm[i][j + 1]) count++;
        }
    }

    fprintf(fileOutput, "\ncount = %d", count);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        delete[] mm[i];
    delete[] mm;
}
void generateMM(int **m, FILE *fileInput, int posInInput) {
    srand(time(NULL));

    fseek(fileInput, posInInput, SEEK_SET);
    fprintf(fileInput, "\n\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            m[i][j] = rand() % 32;
            fprintf(fileInput, "%d ", m[i][j]);
        }
        fprintf(fileInput, "\n");
    }
}
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    FILE *fileInput = NULL;
    FILE *fileOutput = NULL;
    char fileInputName[20], fileOutputName[20];
    int m[20];
    int* p = m;

    int** mm;
    mm = new int*[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        mm[i] = new int[10];

    while (fileInput == NULL) {
        printf("Введите имя файла с исходными данными: ");
        scanf("%s", fileInputName);

        fileInput = fopen(fileInputName, "r+");
        if (fileInput == NULL)printf("\nФайл не найден");
    }
    while (fileOutput == NULL) {
        printf("Введите имя файла с результатами: ");
        scanf("%s", fileOutputName);

        fileOutput = fopen(fileOutputName, "r+");
        if (fileOutput == NULL)printf("\nФайл не найден");
    }

    fclose(fileInput); fclose(fileOutput);
    fclose(fopen(fileInputName, "w")); fclose(fopen(fileOutputName, "w"));
    fileInput = fopen(fileInputName, "r+");
    fileOutput = fopen(fileOutputName, "r+");

    int posInInput = generateM(p, fileInput);
    int posInOutput = findMin(fileInput, fileOutput);

    generateMM(mm, fileInput, posInInput);
    findNearEquals(fileInput, fileOutput, posInInput, posInOutput);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        delete[] mm[i];
    delete[] mm;

    fclose(fileInput);
    fclose(fileOutput);

    getch();
}
```

Comment: Ну так бери и дебажь.

Comment: Кто или что мешает вам воспользоваться отладчиком и увидеть всё своими глазами?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего `strtok` возвращает `NULL` - вы же не проверяете результат? - и получается вызов `strcpy(element,NULL)`...